# Installing TensorFlow in a Virtualenv on OSX

Tags: bash, installation, tensorflow

I am following the [instructions for installing TensorFlow in a virtual environment on Mac](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#virtualenv-based_installation), however I am not sure what this instruction means:

```
(tensor flow)$ pip install --upgrade <$url_to_binary.whl>
```

Specifically the `url_to_binary.whl` bit.

Installation has progressed fine so far. I tried using that exact command but it printed an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I assume that everything between the <> is a placeholder and refers to some location, not sure what though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It's now installed and up and running.

`<$url_to_binary.whl>` should be replaced by `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`

I assume that was the file they meant.

Answer (score 1):

They meant the binary they told about previously in the [binary installation section for MacOS](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#virtualenv-based_installation)

> Only CPU-version is available at the moment.
>
> `$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`

So the path to binary is `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion,you may try like this:

`(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade`

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl