# uninstall virtualenv in mac

Tags: tensorflow, installation, virtualenv

[I try to install tensorflow via virtualenv in mac, the reference is here:](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation)

- for I have python already, so I install virtualenv by:
  `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`
- build a new virtualenv environment in `~/development project/tensorflow`, not in `~/tensorflow` as is said in the reference:

  `virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/development project/tensorflow`

  `cd ~/development project/tensorflow`
- active virtualenv by:

  `source bin/activate  # if use bash,and I choose this line to run`
- when I am in virtualenv and run this:

  `(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade <$url_to_binary.whl>`

  it comes out an error:

  `zsh: parse error near '\n'`
- [then I check here to help solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673583/installing-tensorflow-in-a-virtualenv-on-osx)
  it says that `<$url_to_binary.whl>` should be replaced by `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`, and I do so. And problem gone.
- but, when I try to test tensorflow by cd some dir in tensorflow like:

  `(tensorflow)$ cd tensorflow/models/image/mnist`

  the dir is not exist.

  so I guess the url I modified cause it, and I try to reinstall virtualenv and tensorflow, to make my install clean.
- tensorflow is successfully uninstalled, but when I remove virtualenv, it booms:

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215,
>   in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py",
>   line 76, in run
>       requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346,
>   in uninstall
>       req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line
>   754, in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py",
>   line 115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line
>   267, in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 303, in move
>       os.unlink(src) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

- I delete dir `tensorflow`
- for now I could not uninstall virtualenv neither install it, but it still exist....that's really wired.
- If I run `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv` again, it says:

> The directory '/Users/Calvino/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been
>   disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.   The directory
>   '/Users/Calvino/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not
>   owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check
>   the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
>   sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.   Requirement already up-to-date:
>   virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

My question is that how could I remove virtualenv and tensorflow thoroughly and reinstall them.

I would be very appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

have been two years but anyways yo need to uninstall with >
//Reinstal python 2 or 3 with new SO update

```
brew update
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
brew reinstall python@3
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954182/python-cannot-uninstall-six-while-pip-install-tld)

then reinstall tensorflow with>
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score -1):

Now, you just need to run:

```
 (tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow      # for Python 2.7
 (tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```

And remove by: (this is for virtualenv, you change the path, following path also should be changed to ~/development/project/tensorflow)

```
 $ rm -r ~/tensorflow
```

If you install tensorflow with native pip:

```
$ pip uninstall tensorflow
$ pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

More information: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac